# How to add admin pages to Panopoly Pages

Tags: panels, distributions

I use Panopoly and added admin/content to the page manager and added two variants. My question is, why doesn't the page show under admin/panopoly/pages ?

Which is the concept of the "Panopoly Pages"? I understand that not all pages, which are added to the Page Manager are Panopoly Pages. How is it determined which pages are listed under admin/panopoly/pages?

Comment: What's your end goal here? Why are you creating variants of admin/content?

Comment: I did that to show different content lists to admins and editors. This is for 2 reasons: 1. Certain content types might not be relevant for editors so I would exclude them. An

Comment: 2. For editors I want to structure the content in multiple views with different (exposed) filters (Sorry for the 2 comments, I hit enter accidentally)

Comment: Just set up a new page using views for that with edit and delete links.. Don't go messing with admin pages when you don't need to. And anyways, Panopoly is a page builder for content types so that each node can have a different layout. It has nothing to do with general admin / views pages.

Comment: Thanks Niall, I almost thought it would be like that. I was just amazed by the fact that I _could_ do it. But you're right, that doesn't mean, it's a good thing to do it. Ok, the focus of Panolpoly on "building" content types seems obvious, thanks for making it clear again!